# WPF - Creating simple controls to be used on a Canvas

Tags: wpf, user-interface, canvas, draggable

I'm developing a simple WPF UI for image post-processing.

I'd like to create a draggable WPF control to be used on a Canvas which would look roughly like this:

[http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/884/photoeditor.png http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/884/photoeditor.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/884/photoeditor.png)

Both end points ellipses would be draggable and the line joining them would follow as the end points move.

Now, I know how to implement this by simply adding these elements into a Canvas and then implementing the necessary event handling to make the elements move as they're dragged.  But that's hard to maintain if I ever want to add other types of draggable controls.

What I'd like to do would be to isolate all the handling into its own class (say DragLine), derived either from FrameworkElement or UIElement.  To add this draggable UI element into a Canvas, I'd create an instance of DragLine and just add it to Canvas.Children.  The rest of my program would only see DragLine instances and wouldn't need to worry about the lines or ellipses used to draw the new element.

I'd like to implement the line end points using standard shapes such as the Ellipse rather than drawing all of the UI element myself.  That's because I'd like to re-use the event handling and hit testing these shapes already implement.

Question: is deriving from FrameworkElement the right way to go about this?  The line and end point ellipses would then be just be visual and logical children of in my new class.

If deriving from FrameworkElement is not the recommended way, how would you go about this instead?

If it is, is there a way to simplify its implementation given that the new class would only ever be used on a Canvas (and doesn't need to work well for things like a Grid or a StackPanel)?

Comment: deriving from FrameworkElement is how I would do it. not that that means much in the WPF world.

Comment: Implementing Measure/ArrangeOverrides seemed kind of superfluos given that this new class would be only used on a Canvas (which doesn't try to do anything smart with layout).  Any tips on simplifying these?  

I tried not overriding these and the result was that none of the visual children rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, yes, trying to reinvent things that already exist in the framework because you don't know about them.  Its been a hobby of mine for quite some time.

What you are doing here is trying to create a special type of [adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx).  These are relatively easy to do using the bits that already exist in the framework.  [I suggest you start here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753340.aspx)

Another thing you might want to look at are [Decorators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753412(VS.85).aspx).  Do pretty much the same thing but I think they are more visual.  Which one to use depends on your requirements.

Comment: I am aware of adorners but am not exactly sure how to adapt them for my purpose.  I'm not trying to adorn another element in my GUI, the element I'm writing *is* the thing I want to drag around and it's  not attached to any other element.

I'll look into it one more time though, I wouldn't be surprised to realize I've missed something important.

Comment: Seems like adorners + a &lt;Line /> is exactly what you need.

Comment: Oh, now that I thought about it another time, your solution sounds good.  I'll give it go.

Comment: It was - here's an output of my app: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nurpax/3721686206/

Comment: @Nurpax hey!  That looks great.  Congrats.  Got a link to your project?

Comment: Sorry, I never open sourced it or released it.  Should've sold it to Instagram :)